# Unzipping a .docx file using zipfile library

Tags: python, python-3.7, docx, python-zipfile

I am trying write an application gets information from a table in a word docx file in order to do some analysis on it by putting turning it into a pandas `DataFrame`. The first step is properly reading and the docx file, and to do this, I am following Virantha Ekanayake's guide for [Reading and writing Microsoft Word docx files with Python](https://virantha.com/2013/08/16/reading-and-writing-microsoft-word-docx-files-with-python/).

I'm at the first step where they say to use the `Zipfile` method of the `zipfile` library in order to unzip the docx file into xml files. I adapted the function definitions in the guide into my code (code included below), but when I run my code, I get an error saying that the docx file is "not a zip file".

This person in the guide says that, "At its heart, a docx file is just a zip file (try running unzip on it!)…" I have tried renaming the docx file to a zip file, and it successfully unzips using WinZip. In my program, however, I want to be able to unzip the docx file without having to rename it to a `.zip` file **manually**. Am I able somehow to unzip the docx file without renaming it? ***Or***, if I have to rename it in order to use the `Zipfile` method, how do I do this in my python code?

```py
import zipfile
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

FILE_PATH = 'C:/Users/user/Documents/Python Project'

class Application():
    def __init__(self):
        #debug print('Initialized!')
        xml_content = self.get_word_xml(f'{FILE_PATH}/DocxFile.docx') 
        xml_tree = self.get_xml_tree(xml_content)

    def get_word_xml(self, docx_filename):
        with open(docx_filename) as f:
            zip = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
            xml_content = zip.read('word/document.xml')
        return xml_content

    def get_xml_tree(self, xml_string):
        return (etree.fromstring(xml_string))

a = Application()
a.mainloop()
```

Error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\New_Tool.py", line 39, in <module>
a = Application()
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\New_Tool.py", line 27, in __init__
xml_content = self.get_word_xml(f'{FILE_PATH}/DocxFile.docx')
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\New_Tool.py", line 32, in get_word_xml
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
File "C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1222, in __init__
self._RealGetContents()
File "C:\Progra~1\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1289, in _RealGetContents
raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: `zipfile.ZipFile` doesn't care what the file's name or extension is, so the problem is something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode:

```
with open(docx_filename, 'rb') as f:
```

Comment: Works perfectly now! I'm new to Python, so I'm not surprised that I forgot to put the read binary mode. Thanks!

Comment: Not working for me. I am using latest excel version

Comment: This discussion is about docx files. How does Excel relate to this discussion?